# Get HubContext from outside of Hub using Aspnetcore.signalr libray (not from Controller)

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, signalr-backplane, signalr-2

I am developing SignalR service using AspNetCore.SignalR.

Following is my Hub:

```
public class NotificationHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub
    {
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

Following is Another Context class that i have created to invoke Hub's method on client side:

```
public class NotificationHubContext
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _context;

        public NotificationHubContext(IHubContext<NotificationHub> context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task Broadcast(string groupId, string eventName, object data)
        {
            await _context.Clients.Group(groupId).SendAsync(eventName, data);
        }
    }
```

I would like to Inject reference of NotificationContext class into my own IoC Container so I can just resolve it and call a BroadCast method on it and it should handle sending messages to clients.

I am using Service Bus to listen for messages from another part of the system, once I receive a message from Queue, I would like to notify Connected clients using HubContext from QueueHandler.

[Assembly Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkjBs.png)

Comment: I believe this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299289/how-to-get-signalr-hub-context-in-a-asp-net-core

Comment: @iNovelletto I am trying to use HubContext without using Controller.

Comment: Sorry, then problably this solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318209/asp-net-core-rc2-signalr-hub-context-outside-request-thread

Comment: Which IoC Container are you using, and how have you registered it?

Comment: `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<NotificationHub>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hubContext = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHubContext<Notification>>
```

That resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I design my class as below.

```
public class NotificationHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub
{
    public static IHubContext<NotificationHub> Current { get; set; }
}
```

In your Startup class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    NotificationHub.Current = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHubContext<NotificationFromServerHub>>();

}
```

So, you can use as like this from anywhere.

```
public class MyBizClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        NotificationHub.Current.MyMethod(...);
    }
}
```