# SignalR Core: Hub Context from Static Controller Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-signalr, signalr-2

I'm looking for a way to call a method, from another class in my project, that will then send a message to all clients connected to the `mainHub`

I have a static method where I'm trying to send data to all clients connected to the `mainHub` which is a `SignalR Core` hub. I am able to get the hub's context however, since this method is static, that hub's context requires an object reference.

In regular `SignalR`, I was able to use

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<mainHub>();
```

I could then call this `context.Clients.All`. However, this does not exist in `SignalR Core`.

```
public class utils : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<mainHub> _hubContext;

    public utils(IHubContext<mainHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public static void addManagementLog(sstructs.ManageLog mngLog)
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("newManageLog", mngLog);
    }
}
```

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property utils._hubContext

What's the best way to use this hub context in a static method, or in a way that I can call this `addManagementLog()` method from other classes in this project?

Comment: This might answer the question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299289/how-to-get-signalr-hub-context-in-a-asp-net-core or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318209/asp-net-core-rc2-signalr-hub-context-outside-request-thread/38832879#38832879

Comment: @Nisarg I am already using the solution provided in this question, by using the new IHubContext<> However, the issue is with calling this in a static method.

Comment: Can you set that to a static variable when you get it in the constructor?

Comment: Right, that's what seems to be the issue.
I've been trying different variants of:
```IHubContext<mainHub> cntxt = new IHubContext<mainHub>;
cntxt.Clients.All.SendAsync("newManageLog", mngLog);
```
There's either something wrong with my syntax, or I can't create a static variable of a IHubContext.
"Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface IHubContext<mainHub>"

Comment: This was a long time ago, but I was faced with the same problem. I solved it by setting a public static variable inside the SingalR hub declared as the same type as the context and set in the Startup.cs with an App.Use() clause. This solved my problem and gave me a static variable to reference from the static method without breaking any rules. The compiler was happy, I was happy, and the code worked well. I would be happy to post that as an answer to this question despite it's age if I hear back that it would be helpful and it will be accepted. Apologies for the delayed response.